# voice xml:lang="en-US" xml:gender="Male" name="Microsoft Server Speech Text is always in Female voice

Tags: node.js, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services, bing-speech

I am just trying to develop a function which converts text to speech. The issue here is, the conversion is always happening in the female voice, even though I had specified the `xml:gender` to male. Here is my function, is there anyway I can transform my texts to audio in male voice?

```
textToSpeech("This is a test to check the conversion of text to speech");
function textToSpeech(text: string) {
    const requestOptions: request.CoreOptions = {
        headers: {
            "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": config.speech.bingSpeech.key1,
        }
    };
    request.post(
        `${config.speech.bingSpeech.authEndPoint}/issueToken`,
        requestOptions,
        (err, response, body) => {
            const accessToken = response.body;
            const payLoad = `
            <speak version="1.0" xml:lang="en-US">
            <voice xml:lang="en-US" xml:gender="Male" name="Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, ZiraRus)">
            ${text}
            </voice>
            </speak>
            `;
            const requestOptions: request.CoreOptions = {
                headers: {
                    "X-Microsoft-OutputFormat": "audio-16khz-128kbitrate-mono-mp3",
                    "Content-Type": "application/ssml+xml",
                    "Host": "speech.platform.bing.com",
                    "Content-Length": payLoad.length,
                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
                    "User-Agent": "NodeJS"
                },
                body: payLoad
            };

            request.post(
                config.speech.bingSpeech.synthesizeUrl,
                requestOptions
            ).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + "/output.mp3"));
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I checked the [3.2.1 voice Element](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/) about `gender` and `name` attributes as follows:

> - gender: optional attribute **indicating the preferred gender of the voice to speak the contained text**. Enumerated values are: "male", "female", "neutral", or the empty string "".
> - name: optional attribute **indicating a processor-specific voice name to speak the contained text**. The value may be a space-separated list of names ordered from top preference down or the empty string "". As a result a name must not contain any white space.

Based on your code, I checked the [Supported locales and voice fonts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/bingvoiceoutput#SupLocales):

[image]

For male voice, you may also need to set the `name` attribute of the `voice` element to `Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, BenjaminRUS)`.